# Make a score counter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a score counter but when I use the timer, it's way too slow to get to the high value and it's max interval is 1. Refer code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    y = y + 2
    ShowScore()
    If y = Game2048.ScoreLabel.Text Then
        Label18.Hide()
        Label19.Show()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer2.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see that if the value Game2048.ScoreLabel.Text is 60,000 and Timer1 Interval is 1 then it will take more than 10 minutes to get to 60,000. So I was wondering if there is a way to reduce the time it reaches to 60,000 when counting up score, it is the same like in several games that have the ability to counting up score in just 10 seconds and when the score is higher, the amount it pluses will bigger. Anyone can help me out? Thanks!

*the 60,000 value may change!

Comment: You can either increase the number of point added to the score on each Tick event or reduce the interval between each tick event.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to speed up the timer, the quickest and easiest solution would just to be increment the `y` value by a percentage of the `ScoreLabel` value: `y = y + Integer.Parse(Game2048.ScoreLabel.Text) * 0.10`

Comment: You will not get an interval of 1 millisecond.  Smallest practical value is 15, actual ticks occur at 15.625 msec.  Use the clock to measure actual elapsed time, store DateTime.UtcNow when you start the timer.  Actual timer interval is not important, just make it small enough to make the update look smooth.  45 is good enough.

Comment: If I increase it to the bigger amount, the last amount will not receive 100% correctly. I just want it to increase when possible and when the amount is high

Comment: Then use `Math.Min` to make sure you don't go over: `y = Math.Min(y + scoreNumber * 0.10, scoreNumber)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already ticking faster than the user interface can update, which is already way faster than the human eye can follow. You'll also end up devoting a lot of cpu cycles to meaningless udpates at this rate.

What you want to do is set the tick rate to something reasonably fast from the perspective a human watching the counter. A tick rate of 250ms (4 times per second) ought to be plenty fast, and anything faster than about 100ms (10 times per second) is just wasteful.

Now you can adjust the code to calculate where you want the update to be at that point. If you want to count to 60,000 in 10 seconds, at 4 updates per second, then you have 40 updates, so just set your `y` value to 1500 instead of 2. Or, even better, calculate the rate on the fly:

```
'Set tick rate to 250
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    y += CInt(Game2048.ScoreLabel.Text) / timer1.Interval / 6
    ShowScore()
    If y >= Game2048.ScoreLabel.Text Then
        Label18.Hide()
        Label19.Show()
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer2.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```